# regex remove  etc

Tags: javascript, regex

In previous question (link needed) I try to remove hastags and comments from Twitter. My string is text like this:

```
@lien_ayy92 % Real Avail▶#Jakarta #Bekasi Excl/Incl Expo▶6-7 Juli #Cirebon Wajib DP Cek BIO https://local.com/
```

I want try remove the icons and text that is not important.

My code from previus code

```js
let clean = function (data) {
 data = data.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+|\B[@#]\w+\b|\b\w+[@#]\B|\B[^\w\s]{2,}\B|\b[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\b|[0-9]+|[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-/]|\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g, '');
 return data;
}
let stopwords = function (docs) {
   docs = clean(docs);
 docs = docs.trim(); 
    docs = docs.toLowerCase(); 
 docs = docs.split(' ');
  let wordsstop = ['about'];
 let docs1 = new Array;
  var x =  0;
  for(let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
       if(wordsstop.indexOf(docs[i]) !== -1 || docs[i] == ""){

      }else{
      docs1[x] = docs[i]
      x++;
      }
  }
  return docs1;
}

console.log(stopwords('@lien_ayy92 % Real Avail▶#Jakarta #Bekasi Excl/Incl Expo▶6-7 Juli #Cirebon Wajib DP Cek BIO https://local.com about data'));
```

I want result like this:

```
["real","juli","data"];
```

Comment: It sounds like you should just search for dictionary words... Not use a regex.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/ktpam6zu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove all items with special character.

```js
let clean = function (data) {
 data = data.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+|\B[@#]\w+\b|\b\w+[@#]\B|\B[^\w\s]{2,}\B|\b[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\b|[0-9]+|[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-/]|\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g, '');
 return data;
}
let stopwords = function (docs) {
   docs = clean(docs);
 docs = docs.trim(); 
    docs = docs.toLowerCase(); 
 docs = docs.split(' ');
  let wordsstop = ['about'];
 let docs1 = new Array;
  var x =  0;
  for(let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
       if(wordsstop.indexOf(docs[i]) !== -1 || docs[i] == ""){

      }else{
      docs1[x] = docs[i]
      x++;
      }
  }
  
  // filter code below
  var resultDocs = docs1.filter(function(data) {
    var tmp = data.replace(/[a-zA-Z$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-/]/g, '');
    if (tmp.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  return resultDocs;

}

console.log(stopwords('@lien_ayy92 % Real Avail▶#Jakarta #Bekasi Excl/Incl Expo▶6-7 Juli #Cirebon Wajib DP Cek BIO https://local.com about data'));
```